# Clarification on Spark Aggregate Function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala and Spark. I could not figure out the aggregate function. I have the following code given to me but do not understand the output value.

```
    val z = sc.parallelize(List("12","23","345","4567"),2)

    z.aggregate("")((x,y) => math.min(x.length, y.length).toString, (x,y) => x + y)

    res5: String = 11
```

There are 2 partitions. Initial value provided is "". How the value (x,y) is applied, I am not too sure. But my understanding is, for the first partition, it will iteratively take them to be ("","12") ("12","23") and the min value returned for the first partition is 0. Similarly for the 2nd partition (x,y) iteratively evaluates the min function from ("","345") ("345", "4567") and the min value returned for the second partition is 0.

The reducer function takes over from there aggregating the results "" + "0" + "0" - The final output should be "00" but the actual output is "11"

what am I missing, can someone explain how the aggregate function works for the above code. Especially, I don't get the (x,y) concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can see what's happening by adding some logging:

```
z.aggregate("")((x,y) => {
  val res = math.min(x.length, y.length).toString
  println(s"math.min($x.length, $y.length).toString => $res")
  res
}, (x,y) => {
  println(s"$x + $y => ${x+y}")
  x + y
})
```

Which gives:

```
math.min(.length, 345.length).toString => 0
math.min(.length, 12.length).toString => 0
math.min(0.length, 4567.length).toString => 1
math.min(0.length, 23.length).toString => 1
 + 1 => 1
1 + 1 => 11
```

The first value in each partition is mapped using the zero element given to the aggregate function (to obtain a first value of the new type, which here is also String) and then elements are reduced together inside each partition using the first function. Then the final result of each partition are reduced using the second function.